# How to remove highlight in the google slides API?

Tags: python, google-api, google-slides-api

I am using the Google API Python Client to replace text placeholders with generated data. In this example, I detect all instances of "bar" and replace them with "foo", in all slides. `slides_service` is instantiated with `apiclient.discovery.build(...)`

```
batch_requests_array = [
            {
                "replaceAllText": {
                    "replaceText": "foo",
                    "containsText": {
                        "text": "bar",
                        "matchCase": False
                    }
                }
            }
        ]

        batch_requests = {"requests": batch_requests_array}
        request = slides_service.presentations().batchUpdate(presentationId=slides_id, body=batch_requests)
        res = request.execute()
```

Now if bar has a highlight color, how can I remove that when I replace it with foo? I think I need to add a separate request to my batch requests array, but I have been scrolling up and down here without finding any clue.

For clarity, this is the highlight option I am talking about as it's presented in the UI [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the highlight color of a text, you will have to update the `backgroundColor`. To give you an idea, this is how the request should look, this will set the background fully transparent:

```
highlightedTextRequest = [
    {
        "updateTextStyle": {
            "objectId": "objectId",
            "style": {
                "backgroundColor": {
                }
            },              
        "fields": "*"
        }
    }
]
```

**Note:** The `objectId` in the request, is the ID of the shape or table with the text to be styled.

**References:**

- [UpdateTextStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updatetextstylerequest)
- [Formatting text with the Google Slides API](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/formatting-text-with-the-google-slides-api.html)

Comment: thank you, I will try that out and come back to this post! Somewhat counter-intuitive that it's called background in the API but highlighting in the UI!